# Custom Build Action similar to AndroidResource

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to organise an Android project's layout files. Having already worked with MVC, I tried to apply that architectural pattern to the Android project.

Suppose I have a folder structure in my Android project:

```
Areas > SomeAreaName > Views > details_layout.xml
```

Setting the Build Action on "details_layout.xml" to `AndroidResource` results in an "invalid file path" error which is understandable as Android does not allow for files in different locations other than the predefined "res" folder and subfolders.

Is it possible to create a custom Build Action (e.g. `AndroidResourceMvc`) that can utilise the existing `AndroidResource` Build Action and with the added ability to appropriately map layout files? If so, how would I go about this?

I've looked at the [AndroidResource](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/ee4b983806a25dabec5f06db995a2c367925a1ab/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Utilities/AndroidResource.cs) file and with it being `internal` and `private` I don't really have access to it. Neither am I able to just use the raw source code as it imports some namespaces that I also do not have access to (or I just can't seem to find them if they're publicly available).

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and a Xamarin Android C# project.

Comment: We can only add sub-folders in **Resource->layout** so that we could access the controls like `Resource.Id.xxx` .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Under <ProjectPath>\obj\Debug\100\res\ the "details_layout.xml" is generated except it's under some additional subfolders. So using the example in my question, I have a <ProjectPath>\obj\Debug\100\res\areas\someareaname\views\details_layout.xml. If I could customise the Build Action to follow some convention then I can get the "details_layout.xml" file under the correct directory (so, <ProjectPath>\obj\Debug\100\res\layout\details_layout.xml). I don't entirely understand how the underlying AndroidResource Build Action works so I may be completely off with how I think it works.